# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i've this error:
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'authObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

my deserialize code

```
authObject a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<authObject>(result);
```

my class with json object description:

```
public class authObject
{

        public string auth { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string sess_id { get; set; }

}
```

Ofcourse my json :

```
[{"auth":"49","type":"P","sess_id":"89a0d5gle5vspo0ed3j8tbdos4"}]
```

what i have been done wrongly ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires an *array* or a *list*, try

```
List<authObject>  list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<authObject>>(result);
```

Comment: Instead of saying *it doesn't work*, it would be helpful to state the exceptions (types and messages) you are getting.

Comment: Now i have this error
Can not implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List <authObject>' in 'authObject'.now i have this error: